# Making rbind loop faster

Tags: r, for-loop, tidyverse, rbind

I have a two column dataframe that has the value in the left column and frequency of that value in the right column. I want to reflect this data in a new dataframe that is just one column.

I have got it working with the 2 for loops below, but with my data (100k+ rows and many dataframes) its very slow. I've tried using the apply functions but cant work it out.

```
library(tidyverse)

twocol <- tribble(
  ~value, ~count,
  0.23076923, 5,
  0.69076923, 3,
  1.15230769, 4,
  1.61384615, 4,
  2.15230769, 3
) %>% as.data.frame()

make_onecol <- function(df) {
  dfnew <- data.frame(value=NA)
  df %>% filter(count!=0) -> df
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    n <- df[i, 2]
    for (j in 1:n) {
      dfnew <- rbind(dfnew, df[i, 1])
    }
  }
  return(dfnew)
}

onecol <- make_onecol(twocol)
```

Comment: I don't speak tidyverse but is your goal to repeat each `value` `count` times? Then you can simply do `rep(twocol$value, twocol$count)`

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the `rep`-function for that. Using:

```
onecol <- data.frame(value = c(NA, rep(twocol$value, twocol$count)))
```

gives:

> ```
> > onecol
>        value
> 1         NA
> 2  0.2307692
> 3  0.2307692
> 4  0.2307692
> 5  0.2307692
> 6  0.2307692
> 7  0.6907692
> 8  0.6907692
> 9  0.6907692
> 10 1.1523077
> 11 1.1523077
> 12 1.1523077
> 13 1.1523077
> 14 1.6138462
> 15 1.6138462
> 16 1.6138462
> 17 1.6138462
> 18 2.1523077
> 19 2.1523077
> 20 2.1523077
> ```

Comment: Perfect thank you! Man I went to a lot of trouble for nothing! :)

Answer (score 1):

`rep` wrapper with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(twocol)[, .(value = rep(value, count))]
#     value
# 0.2307692
# 0.2307692
# 0.2307692
# 0.2307692
# 0.2307692
# 0.6907692
# 0.6907692
# 0.6907692
# 1.1523077
# 1.1523077
# 1.1523077
# 1.1523077
# ...
```

Comment: your earlier solution `data.frame(value = with(two_col, rep(value, count)))` is performing better than `data.table` when generating 150000 rows. I haven't checked with more number of rows.